# jQuery how to get html table id above button after clicked

Tags: jquery, html, button, html-table

I have an html table followed by a button that says "Add Row" below it.

When I click on the button, I would like to add a new row onto the html table but first I need to get the html table id above.

Is there anyway in jQuery to say "Give me the id of the html table right before this button"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("button").click(function(){
  var tblID = $(this).prev("table:first").attr("id");
});
```