# How can I get the above table on button click?

Tags: jquery

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081943/jquery-how-to-get-html-table-id-above-button-after-clicked), but it's not working for me. I've also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310270/jquery-find-closest-previous-sibling-with-class) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328080/jquery-finding-previous-div), but still not working.

I need to get the table ID above the clicked button.
If I click the top button (remove request div) I would get table t1 ID.

My code looks like this:

```
<table id="t1"></table>

<div class="bulk_action">
  <div title="Remove requests" class="trash_iconset_grey_16px removeRequest"></div>
  <div title="some other button" class="abc"></div>
</div>

<table id="t2"></table>

<div class="bulk_action">
  <div title="Remove requests" class="trash_iconset_grey_16px removeRequest"></div>
  <div title="some other button" class="abc"></div>
</div>
```

JS code

```
jQuery('.removeRequest').live ('click', function(){
  var div_obj = jQuery(this).closest('div');
  //alert(jQuery(div_obj).attr('class')); //<-- this works

  var tbl = jQuery(div_obj).prev('table:first'); // <-- This is not working
  alert(jQuery(tbl).attr('id'));
});
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By going to the parent of the button, you can then ask for the closest table:

```
jQuery('.removeRequest').live('click', function(){
  var div_obj = $(this).parent();
  var tbl = div_obj.prev('table');
  alert(tbl.attr('id'));
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XNWsy/1/

Comment: As I said in my answer, you don't need to enclose `div_obj` in `$()`, it's already a jquery object!!! See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNWsy/1/) as proof that it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to construct a new jQuery object for the div when looking for the table. It's already a jQuery object. I mean, use this:

```
var tbl = div_obj.closest('table'); 
alert(tbl.attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.prev` if your markup structure is same always,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/evR5M/1/)

```
jQuery('.removeRequest').live ('click', function(){
  var div_obj = jQuery(this).closest('div');
  alert(jQuery(div_obj).attr('class')); //<-- this works

  var tbl = jQuery(this).closest('.bulk_action').prev(); // <-- Will get you the table
  alert(tbl.attr('id'));
});
```

or If the markup may have some elements between the div and the table then use `.closest('table')` like below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/evR5M/)

```
jQuery('.removeRequest').live ('click', function(){
  var div_obj = jQuery(this).closest('div');
  //alert(jQuery(div_obj).attr('class')); //<-- this works

  var tbl = jQuery(this).closest('.bulk_action').prev('table'); // <-- Will get you the table
  alert(jQuery(tbl).attr('id'));
});
```

**Note:** Use `.on` if you are using jQuery version 1.7 or use `.delegate` for older versions.

Using `.on` (for jQuery v1.7)

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.removeRequest', function(){
```

Using `.delegate` (for older versions)

```
jQuery(document).delegate ('.removeRequest', 'click', function(){
```

**PS:** replace `jQuery(document)` with any wrapper selector that wraps the div and the tables.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this might work:

```
jQuery('.removeRequest').live ('click', function(){
    var tbl = jQuery(this).closest("table");
    alert(jQuery(tbl).attr('id'));
});
```